# jQuery .each function in a table not working

Tags: jquery, html-table, each

I'm trying to get an .each function going on the "Deltree" div that selects the `.attr('class')` for each div and alerts me of its value, but it's only working on the first of the deltree div's. Here's my table:

```
<table width="100%" style="border:1px solid #ccc;">
<tbody>

<tr id="links"><td id="linkname"><a href="http://www.vg.no">vg</a></td><td id="link"><a href="http://www.vg.no">http://www.vg.no</a></td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td><div class="1" id="deltree">Slett</div></td></tr>

<tr id="links"><td id="linkname"><a href="http://www.dt.no">test</a></td><td id="link"><a href="http://www.dt.no">http://www.dt.no</a></td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td><div class="2" id="deltree">Slett</div></td></tr>

<tr id="links"><td id="linkname"><a href="http://www.vg.no">vg2</a></td><td id="link"><a href="http://www.vg.no">http://www.vg.no</a></td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td><div class="3" id="deltree">Slett</div></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Here's my script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#links').each(function() {
    $('#deltree').click(function() {
    var lid = $(this).attr("class");  
    var dataString = 'lid='+ lid;  
alert(dataString);
    }); 
    }); 
  });
```

It just refuses to alert me when I click on the other 2 div's, and I can't figure out why. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: In a general way, it is not correct to have multiple elements with the same id.

Comment: use deltree as class not as id, since ids meant to be unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`id` is supposed to be unique per page - so jQuery finds the first element (using getElementById function, I suppose), processes it and stops. You should use `name` attribute and appropriate jQuery selector (`$('div[name="deltree"]')`) instead.

**Sample code**

Table:

```
<table width="100%" style="border:1px solid #ccc;">
<tbody>

    <tr id="links">... skipped ...<div class="1" name="deltree">Slett</div></td></tr>

    <tr id="links">... skipped ...<div class="2" name="deltree">Slett</div></td></tr>

    <tr id="links">... skipped ...<div class="3" name="deltree">Slett</div></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#links').each(function() {
    $('div[name="deltree"]').click(function() {
    var lid = $(this).attr("class");  
    var dataString = 'lid='+ lid;  
alert(dataString);
    }); 
    }); 
  });
```

Comment: Thank you! changed it around to class and name and it works =)

Comment: @Havihavi. Don't change to class and name. Just one of them... **(-:**

Answer (score 1):

Use ***class*** instead of ***id***, then a $(".classname') selector. Ids must be unique.

Answer (score 1):

When you have multiple elements with same `id` you can't really know what will happen.
`id` should be unique.

change `id` to be `name`

```
<table width="100%" style="border:1px solid #ccc;">
<tbody>

<tr name ="links"><td id="linkname"><a href="http://www.vg.no">vg</a></td><td id="link"><a href="http://www.vg.no">http://www.vg.no</a></td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td><div class="1" id="deltree">Slett</div></td></tr>

<tr name="links"><td id="linkname"><a href="http://www.dt.no">test</a></td><td id="link"><a href="http://www.dt.no">http://www.dt.no</a></td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td><div class="2" id="deltree">Slett</div></td></tr>

<tr name="links"><td id="linkname"><a href="http://www.vg.no">vg2</a></td><td id="link"><a href="http://www.vg.no">http://www.vg.no</a></td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td><div class="3" id="deltree">Slett</div></td></tr></tbody></table>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name=links]').each(function() {
        $('#deltree').click(function() {
        var lid = $(this).attr("class");  
        var dataString = 'lid='+ lid;  
        alert(dataString);
        }); 
    }); 
  });
```